# Update existing relationship property value in Neo4j using CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I already have some data in Neo4j, data is modelled in the below fashion :

```
:A {ID:"123",Group:"ABC",Family:"XYZ"}
:B {ID:"456",Group:"ABC",Family:"XYZ"})
(:A)-[:SCORE{score:'2'}]-(:B)
```

Please find the attached image for more clarification how data looks like currently.[image]

Now,
I am importing some new data through CSV file which has 5 columns

1. A's ID
2. B's ID
3. Score through which A is attached to B
4. Group
5. Family

In the new data there can be some new A Ids or some new B Ids

Question :

1. I want to create those new nodes of type A and B and create a relationship 'Score' and assigning score as the value of relationship type 'Score' between them
2. there are chances that there already existing scores between A and B might have changed. So i want to just update the previous score with the new one.

How to write cypher to achieve the above problem using CSV as import.

I used the below cypher query to model data for the first time:

```
using periodic commit LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ABC.csv" as line Merge(a:A{ID: line.A,Group:line.Group,Family:line.Family})
Merge(b:B{ID: line.A,Group:line.Group,Family:line.Family})
Merge(a)-[:Score{score:toFloat(line.Score)}]-(b)
```

Note: Family and Group are same for both type of nodes 'A' and 'B'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `MERGE` the relationship and set the score after the fact so it does not create new SCORE relationships for every new value.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ABC.csv" AS line
MERGE (a:A {ID: line.A, Group:line.Group, Family:line.Family})
MERGE (b:B {ID: line.A, Group:line.Group, Family:line.Family})
MERGE (a)-[score:SCORE]-(b)
SET score.score = toFloat(line.Score)
```